# How do I create a standalone mode extension for ACE?

Tags: ace-editor

I'd like to extend ace with a mode for a custom language.  As far as I can tell, the general process is:

1. Download the ace source.
2. Create a new lib/ace/mode/foo.js for your custom language.
3. run "make build" (or similar) to rebuild ACE.
4. Use the newly compiled build/src-min-no-conflict (or whatever) ACE distribution in your website.

But I want to just use an existing ACE distribution from their website, combined with my standalone new mode.  I don't want to have to rebuild ACE as part of my build process in order to build my new mode.  I got close by doing:

```
ace.config.setModuleUrl("foo-mode", "./foo.js");
session.setMode("foo-mode");
```

But I quickly ran into requirejs / dependency problems.  For instance I couldn't do `require("ace/mode/matching_brace_outdent")` inside my mode.  I temporarily hacked around that by first calling `setMode('ace/mode/c_cpp')` (which as a byproduct defines the matching_brace_outdent module).  But I ran into even worse problems trying to get a custom WorkerClient to work.

Is my only option to build my mode as part of ACE?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try the pre-built release.

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/releases

You might need to edit other files (lists of modes etc.) depending on how you wish to present your new language in the UI:

Answer (score 1):

With regards to `require` under no-conflict mode in custom modes that aren't workers, if you define your custom mode as a module or a series of modules inside `define` or `ace.define`, you should just be able to use the `require` provided to you in the function wrapper:

```js
ace.define("ace/mode/your_module_name",
        ["require","exports","module","ace/your_other_dependencies"],
        function(require, exports, module) {

    // you can use require('...') here
});
```

I believe you can also use `ace.require`.

I am less sure about how to "manually build" a custom worker, but following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42632568/3243497), I think I got it to work by copying code around the core of the [relatively slim `worker-json.js`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/worker-json.js#L1409-L1699).