# How to use mirror worker for ace editor with ace-builds

Tags: ace-editor

I am using [ace-builds](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds) to build my ace editor app with webpack.

I need to use a custom worker for syntax validation. The wiki page [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Syntax-validation) suggests to extend a worker named `mirror` obtained by following.

`var Mirror = require("ace/worker/mirror").Mirror;`

But ace-builds does not seem to provide this worker. How do I create a custom worker for syntax validation using ace-builds?

Any other advice on how to build an ace editor app with a custom syntax validating worker (for a custom programming language) is much appreciated. (I cannot use the ace library supposed to be used with require.js, as it uses `require.toUrl` which webpack does not know about. See [github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/997))

Answer (score 1):

ace-builds repository provides only built workers, and doesn't have source of ace/worker/mirror in a separate file.

You can use json worker to bootstrap your custom one, since it contains only 200 lines of extra code https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/worker-json.js#L1409-L1699

rename that file to `"<mymode>_worker.js"` and add worker definition at the end.

```
define("ace/mode/<mymode>_worker",["require","exports","module"], function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var Mirror = require("../worker/mirror").Mirror;

...

});
```

Comment: But that also depends on mirror worker. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/worker-json.js#L1663 So only these 200 lines would not work no?  

What I am doing now is copying the definition of mirror worker from any of the worker files and require that file. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/worker-json.js#L1347-L1407 Then the mirror worker is defined. But I'd like to avoid putting other peoples code directly in my repo :)

Comment: It contains definition of mirror, and all of its dependencies https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/v1.2.6/src/worker-json.js#L1347, everything other than the highlighted 200 lines in that file is needed to create a webWorker for ace. So i was suggesting to include full worker-json.js file in your webpack config for the worker

Comment: ah. so if I require worker-json file, can I avoid requiring [ace.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/v1.2.6/src/ace.js) file? I'll give it a try. Thanks.